# Axioms of noncommutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, axioms, noncommutative-algebra

Is there an abelian group $R$ with multiplication operator with this properties ?

(i) $a(bc)=(ab)c$
(ii) $a(b+c)=ab+ac$  , $(b+c)a=ba+ca$

> And a *unique* element $e$ s.t
>   (iii) $ea=a\quad \forall a\in R $

But there exists $x\in R$ s.t $xe\neq x$ .

Comment: You are looking for a structure with only a left identity and no right identity. There are structures which have more than one left identity, however this implies that there exists no right identity.

Comment: @Ed_4434 It's not possible in noncommutative rings? What is your proof?

Comment: In any ring the additive identity and (if there is one) the multiplicative identity are unique.

Comment: @Ed_4434 $e$ is not multiplicative identity .

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. You've asked if there is an Abelian group $R$ under multiplication with element $e$ such that $ea = a$, yet $e$ is not a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @Ed_4434 $(R,+)$ is an abelian group, but $(R,\times)$ is not a group.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks, but I'm  looking for the structure with only one left identity, all the answers have more than one left identity.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't very clear from your question. Then read this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1392057/10014

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks . My question is duplicate!

Comment: It is indeed. Since I had already cast a vote for the (wrong) previous one I cannot cast one again, but hopefully someone will.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was inspired by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293167/about-right-identity-which-is-not-left-identity-in-a-ring).
Consider the set $R$ of matrices with integer entries of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & a\\ b & b \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $R$ is an abelian group under addition and a semigroup under the multiplication of matrices. Distributivity also holds. Now, the formula
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & a\\ b & b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x & x\\ y & y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a(x+y) & a(x+y)\\ b(x+y) & b(x+y) \end{pmatrix}
$$
shows that every matrix 
$\begin{pmatrix} x & x\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ such that $x + y = 1$ is a right identity. However, there is no left identity. You can of course take the dual operation if you wish to have a left identity and no right identity, like in your question.

Comment: Thanks , but i'm looking for the structure that have only one left identity. your example is very good but has infinite many identity.