# Ring with left identity but no right identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Are there any rings that have a left identity but do not have a right identity?

Comment: if $e$ is a unique left identity, this is [impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392057/if-there-is-a-unique-left-identity-then-it-is-also-a-right-identity) but you can [construct examples that have more than one left identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293167/about-right-identity-which-is-not-left-identity-in-a-ring).

Comment: @AndresMejia so in your second linked example, say we take the same setup but instead have the condition that a+b=1 must hold. Would this then satisfy left identity but not right identity?

Comment: You can fix that immediately by dualizing the example (AKA) take the transpose.